# XMLConnect - Admin functions

Tags: magento-1.9, api, extensions

I am trying to build an android app for magento. I wish to leverage magento XML connect for this. Currently I am unable to call any of the admin URL's(with XML connect). All of them return a 404 error.

a sample url is:
http://localhost/magento/admin/xmlconnect/user/login
returns 404(not found)

Please let know if i am doing anything wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've to go with `{magentopath}/admin/connect_user/login`

Also make sure to check `etc/modules/Mage_Xmlconnect.xml` when upgrading to 1.9.1.0 because it is **disabled** by default since 1.9.1.0

Comment: could you accept this as an answer so other users know this is the answer to? Thanks